# How can I implement addFields mongoDB query in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have found several example at StackOverFlow related to addFields in Aggregation.
But no one implemented in Java.

```js
db.getCollection('myDocument').aggregate([
    {$match : {"metaId.ref.uuid" : "d6112808-1ce1-4545-bd52-cf55bc4ed25e"}},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "simple",
        localField: "someId.ref.uuid",
        foreignField: "uuid", 
        as: "simple"}},
    {"$unwind": "$simple"},
    {"$addFields": { "metaId.ref.name" : "$simple.name" }}
])
```

I am not able to Implement In Java Correctly:-- Not getting proper procedure

```java
LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
    .from("simple")
    .localField("execId.ref.uuid")
    .foreignField("uuid")
    .as("simple");
Aggregation myDocAggr = new Aggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("metaId.ref.uuid").is(someUUID)), 
    group("uuid").max("version").as("version"),
    lookupOperation,
    Aggregates.unwind(""),
    Aggregates.addFields(fields));
Document document = new Document();
AggregationResults<String> myDocAggrResults =
    mongoTemplate.aggregate(myDocAggr, myDocument, myDocument.class);
List<String> mydocumentList = myDocAggrResults .getMappedResults();
```

Not able to use unwind and addFields, this is sample java code, but it is not ok.
Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: which error/stacktrace?

Comment: what is the compilation error saying?

Comment: I guess there is at least a closing bracket missing

Comment: After `Aggregates.unwind(""),` there should be some closing brackets? what arguments are you trying to give to the method call?

Comment: Which `newAggregation` method do you try to invoke?

Comment: I see only two arguments `Class<T>, List<? extends AggregationOperation>`. What do you see?

Comment: Aggregation myDocAggr = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("metaId.ref.uuid").is(datapodUUID)), group("uuid").max("version").as("version"),
    lookupOperation); Works correctly but If try to add unwind,it gives me start giving error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183495/discussion-between-sheel-and-michaeak).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are mixing the java driver `Aggregates` method with Spring `Aggregation` methods.

Also `$addFields` is still [`not supported`](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1887) in spring mongo.

You have to use below aggregation.

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;
Aggregation myDocAggr = newAggregation(
       match(Criteria.where("metaId.ref.uuid").is(someUUID)), 
       group("uuid").max("version").as("version"),
       lookup("simple","execId.ref.uuid","uuid","simple"),
       unwind("simple"),
       new AggregationOperation(){ 
         @Override 
         public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aoc) {
            return new Document("$addFields",new Document("metaId.ref.name","$simple.name"));
         }
      }
)
List<Document> mydocumentList=mongoTemplate.aggregate(myDocAggr,"myDocument",Document.class).getMappedResults();
```

Comment: which version of spring you are using for this code snippet, I am not able to add unwind and lookup in mine code.

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution :-) Although unwind did not work for me, but I got a way to implement it.

Comment: You are welcome. Use `import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;`. It has all the aggregation operators.

Comment: I have constraints, cannot use monogo_spring_data greater than 1.90 so I have switched to mongo java driver, because I have huge records, want to use the cursor, Please let me know how can I add fields, using java.

Comment: Don't mix & match spring aggregation with java driver aggregation. Something like `Aggregates.addFields(new Field("metaId.ref.name", "$simple.name"))` should work for java driver. Convert rest of the aggregation operators to use java driver.

Comment: thank you, you just advised a generic way to use any MongoDB aggregations that haven't yet been implemented in Spring Data. Just return Document.parse("any json here") from toDocument()

Answer (score 7):

Since version 3.0 of 'spring-data-mongodb' it is actually possible to create a AddField aggration very easily. You can use the [AddFieldsOperationBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AddFieldsOperation.AddFieldsOperationBuilder.html).

In the example below I add a string id field for the objectId field named `_id`.
The string field `idString` can get used in a lookup aggregation.

Example:

```
    AddFieldsOperation addFieldsOperation = Aggregation.addFields().addFieldWithValue("idString", ConvertOperators.ToString.toString("$_id")).build();
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how to add values of two other field and put as the value for the new field?

Answer (score 4):

Although the $addFields are not supported by spring mongo you can implement it by yourself:

```
import org.bson.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.*;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AddFieldsOperation implements FieldsExposingAggregationOperation {
    private Map<String, Object> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public AddFieldsOperation(String field, AggregationExpression expression) {
        addField(field, expression);
    }

    public AddFieldsOperation addField(String field, AggregationExpression expression) {
        this.fields.put(field, expression.toDocument(Aggregation.DEFAULT_CONTEXT));
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        Document doc = new Document();
        fields.forEach(doc::append);
        return new Document("$addFields", doc);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean inheritsFields() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ExposedFields getFields() {
        final String[] fieldsArray = fields.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
        return ExposedFields.synthetic(Fields.fields(fieldsArray));
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
...
ArithmeticOperators.Add value1 = ArithmeticOperators.Add.valueOf(0);
ArithmeticOperators.Add value2 = ArithmeticOperators.Add.valueOf(0);
AddFieldsOperation addFields
            = new AddFieldsOperation("value1", value1)
            .addField("value2", value2);
pipeline.add(addFields);
...
Add value1PlusValue2 = Add.valueOf("$value1").add("$value2");
...
```

Hope it will help someone.